# Python "in" magic method?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a magic method in python for the "in" method?
For example,

```
y = [5, 4, 3, 2,1]
5 in y #returns true
```

if so what is it, and if not, how would one implement it.

Comment: Try it and you'll know.

Comment: Special methods are documented in section 3.3 of the reference manual, which has subsections like 3.3.6 'Emulating Container Types'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's [`__contains__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__):

```
>>> y = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
>>> y.__contains__(3)
True
>>> y.__contains__(6)
False
```